# How to keep the screen awake in Trusted Web Activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, trusted-web-activity

I need help regarding Trusted Web Activity. My app works fine, but I need to add a function that keeps the screen awake without user interaction.

I am converting my website into a mobile application using Trusted Web Activity through Android Studio, but how can I keep the Trusted Web Activity screen awake while the user is using app but not interacting. Trusted Web Activity is not using an Android Activity and XML layouts, so it's not possible to use the [Android Wake Lock API](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock). How can I implement in the Trusted Web Activity or the web application?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? The screen will be awake while the user is interacting with it, so I'm guessing the goal is to keep it awake without user interaction, with a screen lock. Is this right?

Comment: yes, when user opens app the screen will keep awake until user close app manually.

Plz guide if you know any solution thanks

Comment: You can use the Wake Lock API for this: https://web.dev/wake-lock/

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply brother i am new bee how i use this please guide me thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Trusted Web Activity is like a browser tab without UI. The same web APIs that work in the browser should also work when running in the Trusted Web Activity mode.

Having said that, web [Wake Lock API](https://web.dev/wake-lock), available web applications, can be used prevent the screen from turning off on the web app. The linked article provides instructions on how to use it.